# Why does python not allow positional arguments after keyword arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I am aware that positional arguments can't follow keyword arguments in python. For example, this code:

```py
def myfunction(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    pass

myfunction(arg3=1, 2)
```

will generate this error:

`SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`

My question is *why* this happens. Can't python see the code like this?

```py
myfunction(arg3=1, arg1=2)
```

It's not a *problem* that positional arguments can't follow keyword arguments. However, in my opinion, it would be much more convenient if this wasn't a thing.

So, my question is, what is the technical reason for not allowing positional arguments to follow keyword arguments? Is it impossible? Is it limited because of a design choice?

Comment: "Can't python see the code like this?" - it *could*, quite easily, but doing so would just be error-prone and confusing instead of actually useful. The fact that a feature is possible doesn't make it a good inclusion in the language.

Comment: I don't know whether there's an implementation constraint, but taking into account that keyword arguments are also positional, I think it's healthy to enforce this at least as a good practice.

Comment: "Can't python see the code like this?" Suppose I think it should instead see the code as `myfunction(arg3=1, arg2=2)`. Why am I wrong? If both interpretations make sense, then what should be the basis for Python to choose, and why?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly What do you mean by "keyword arguments are also positional"?

Code like this is not valid:
```
def a(*args):
    print(args)

a(0, hi=1)
```

Comment: I was assuming something like `def myfunction(arg1, arg2=foo)`. For keywords defined with the `**kwargs` syntax you may want to check [PEP 468](https://peps.python.org/pep-0468/).